# OOP Javascript - Is "get property" method necessary?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

Given a very simple js object constructor and its prototype...

```
    function MyTest(name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    MyTest.prototype =
    {
        getName: function()
        {
            var myName = this.name;
            return myName;
        },
        myMethod: function()
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

Now, in myMethod, is there any difference between using "this.getName" and "this.name"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on whether `name` is an object nor a primitive (boolean, string, int).

If `name` is a primitive/ string, and you use `this.getName()`, you won't be able to modify the value of `this.name` by doing this (assuming `this.name = "Billy"`)

```
this.getName() = "213" //this.name still has a value of "Billy"
```

If `name` is an object `this.name = { firstName: "Billy", lastName: "Bob"};`

```
this.getName().firstName = "Willy"; //this.name now has a value of { firstName: "Willy", lastName: "Bob"}
```

This is due to JavaScript passing primitives by value, but passing objects by reference.

Answer (score 3):

Using the function is slightly slower, but allows you to change how it works in the future (or to do so in another object type that inherits from this one).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. This is not how you implement private vars in JS if that is what you want.