# OO Javascript - Objects instantiation in Object.prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, design-patterns, prototype

Suppose we have 3 chapters of a book and that they are located on their own URL like this:

- Chapter 1 = /1.html
- Chapter 2 = /2.html
- Chapter 3 = /3.html

Now suppose we want to think OO and create 2 JS objects (with the help of jQuery):

- **Chapter**: which loads the chapter into an element, and
- **Book**: which vertically displays the chapters (one after the other).

JS code:

```
// Chapter
function Chapter(chapterId)
{
    this.chapterId = chapterId;
}

Chapter.prototype =
{
    getChapterId: function()
    {
        var chapterId = this.chapterId;
        return chapterId;
    },
    loadChapter: function(el)
    {
        $(el).load( this.getChapterId + ".html" ); // Ajax
    }
}

// Book
function Book()
{
    // ?
}

Book.prototype =
{
    // ?
}
```

In your opinion, thinking object-oriented, what's the best way to define the object "Book", along with methods in its prototype?

What's the most elegant way to handle the instantiation of the objects "Chapter" in Book.prototype?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just pass the chapter ids as a parameter in `Book` and load the chapters in an array. Something like this:

```
// Book
function Book(chapters) {
  this.chapters = chapters.map(function(id){ return new Chapter(id) });
}

var book = new Book([1,2,3,4]);
```

Then you can create methods to loop the chapters and manipulate them as needed.

Comment: Thank you @elclanrs. I'm a bit confused from the different answers. Do you have the chance to write a more complete working example? Which is the best way to instantiate objects of type "Chapter" into the Book object definition (including the loop/cycle)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this :

```
(function (namespace, chapterId) {

    var Chapter = function (chapterId) {
        this.chapterId = chapterId;
    }

    Chapter.prototype ={
    getChapterId: function () {
        var chapterId = this.chapterId;
        return chapterId;
    },

    loadChapter: function (el) {
        $(el).load(this.getChapterId + ".html"); // Ajax
    }}

    namespace.Chapter = Chapter;
})(new Book(), chapterId);
```

Comment: Approach for what? It's the copy/paste of what I wrote. Sorry, it does not answer the question.

Comment: No problem, but still do not understand your answer. Where's the Book object definition (which is supposed to instantiate some objects of type "Chapter")?

Answer (score 0):

Ah I didn't read your question well before. I would do something like this:

```
// Chapter
var Chapter = function(chapterId) {
    this.chapterId = chapterId;
}

Chapter.prototype.loadChapter: function(el) {
    $(el).load( this.chapterId + ".html" ); // Ajax
}


// Book
var Book = function(chapters) {
    this.chapters = (chapters) ? chapters : [];
    this.numberOfChapters = (chapters) ? chapters : 0; 
    // assume that this has to make sence, so if it is number of chapters, 
    // it start with 0.
}

Book.prototype.addChapter = function () {
    this.chapters.push(new Chapter(++this.numberOfChapters));
}
```

Comment: About the reason why I'm using this.getChapterId: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173289/oop-javascript-is-get-property-method-necessary

Comment: I agree with "Keep it simple" but - name? Author? Who mentioned them? I'm just asking how to define a Book object which is supposed to use the Chapter object. Thank you.

Comment: About this.getChapterId I still dont agree. The explanation is not correct! Watch how to make private variables, then you can use them. http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=doug+crockford+javascript+patterns+2013&oq=doug&gs_l=youtube.3.0.35i39l2j0l8.330.1769.0.2991.5.5.0.0.0.0.61.275.5.5.0...0.0...1ac.1.11.youtube.aAYyg-651vE

Comment: Thank you for the video. Am I wrong or in your edit the Book object is not yet using the Chapter object? Where is the "new" operator?